# String comparison using a file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file and it contains a list of strings in the format;

> apple,
>
> dad,
>
> mother,
>
> sister,
>
> brother,
>
> cat,

And i have a sentence as `My dad is a vegetarian`. I need to check if there are any text in my sentence that matches that in the text file.

My code:

```
def matchString(t):
    with open("fil.txt") as fle:

        for item in fle:
         if( fle.readlines()== ) # I couldn't code after this point.
```

What i want to do is to check if a string in this text `My dad is a vegetarian` matches any string in the file, i want to print it to the console thereafter.

Comment: If you're on a Unix system, you could just use `grep` (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep).

Comment: For python look at the re - http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html module.

Comment: Please specify the matching rules more precisely. Do you want to split at word boundaries, or do you want to match substrings as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split the sentence at word boundaries and match those words against words from the file, it can be as simple as

```
for item in fle:
    if item.rstrip(',').strip() in sentence.split():
        # Match
        print item
```

If you want to do substring matching against `sentence`, just leaving of the `.split()` will test if that substring appears anywhere in `sentence`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import re

s = "My dad is a vegetarian"
words = s.split(" ")
pattern = re.compile('^(%s),?$' % "|".join(words))

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    print [row.rstrip() for row in f if pattern.match(row)]
```

prints

```
['dad,']
```

Comment: Your last line could be simplfied to `print pattern.match(row).groups()` if you compile the re beforehand (which one probably should).

Comment: Well, thanks, but, as far as I know, `re` is clever enough to cache the compiled pattern. Though, agreed :)

Comment: Oh? Sweet! :) I just meant, if you're going through the trouble of `OR`ing all those nice groups, you could also use `.groups()` to represent the results. But that will fail if there's no match, so forget what I said ;)